# Reading .ofx,.qif file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file

i want to read the .ofx and .qif files using asp.net.
Can any one please help me in this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

http://qif.codeplex.com/ contains an open-source API for reading QIF files from .NET.
There are several others if you search for QIF or OFX on CodePlex.

OFX is XML with a quirky header.  Examples and specs can be found at http://www.ofx.net.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a program (and not code) then try [iCreateOFX Basic](http://icreateofx.co.uk/basic.php).
It reads QIF, OFX and CSV files into a grid.