# (.OFX/.QFX/.QIF/.QBO/.OFC) file converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ofx, qif

We are building an application that reads files (.OFX/.QFX/.QIF/.QBO/.OFC) and place the data read in the file in a grid.

Does anyone know of a utility or 3rd party tool to convert the file types (.OFX/.QFX/.QIF/.QBO/.OFC) to something more conventional like XML or CSV. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

We are using c#/ASP.NET for developing out web application. The app is hosted on a Windows server if it makes any difference...

Comment: IS this any help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790055/reading-ofx-qif-file-in-asp-net

Simon

Comment: Hi Simon. Not really mate. Saw that earlier. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

Bank2CSV Pro converts various bank, credit card and investment files (QIF, OFX, QFX, QBO, OFC) into CSV format (the file will become a table like a regular spreadsheet with rows as transactions. It supports command line mode:

bank2csv_pro.exe input.ofx output.csv

See http://www.propersoft.net/

Answer (score 5):

[fixofx](https://github.com/wesabe/fixofx) was open sourced from Wesabe. It converts various types of financial files including OFX 1.0 and QIF files to OFX 2.0, which is an XML-based format and so is easily parsed.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Python script [ofx2csv.py](https://gist.github.com/whistler/e7c21c70d1cbb9c4b15d) that converts OFX/QFX files to CSV, if anyone needs to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Bank2CSV Pro works well but the free version converts only 10 transactions and the full version costs USD 50. I found a free online tool that converts CSV to OFX and QIF:

http://csvconverter.gginternational.net/

Just upload your csv, select the fields to map and boom - you get your QIF or OFX file. Worked really well for me when I tried to upload my bank files to QBO

Comment: CSV2QIF at https://www.propersoft.net/csv2qif/ and CSV2OFX at https://www.propersoft.net/csv2ofx/ are converters covering CSV to QIF and CSV to OFX conversion.

Comment: Don't know anything about that site in particular, but I'd think carefully before uploading your bank transactions ANYWHERE!

Answer (score 1):

The  ofx2csv.py script almost works. For the citibank downloads where the csv does not include the 'memo' field and qfx does, I needed to add the memo field to output:

```
line = {
        'date': transaction.date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT),
        'payee': transaction.payee,
        'memo':transaction.memo,
        'debit': debit,
        'credit': credit,
        'balance': balance
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are loking for code to accomplish this or for a utility that does it on the desktop. If it i the latter, then try [iCreateOFX Basic](http://icreateofx.co.uk/basic.php) which reads OFX and QIF files as well as CSV files into a grid.

Comment: It does not really cover the entire spectrum of files I need to convert. But thank you for taking the time to post an answer

Comment: Actually reads OFX variants including QFX files using the OFX file script, plus CSV and QIF files. It will also write to QIF, OFX and CSV files.